# PyQt: garbage collector destroys QModelIndex

Tags: python-3.x, garbage-collection, pyqt

I have a model that is purposefully abstract. I don't want to create an item object for every element in the model so I can't use QSimpleItem Model. Think of it as a giant matrix that is sparse and only the set elements are stored. The matrix is organized as a tree with the rows as top items and row*column as children.

I have the following code to create QModelIndexes for a QAbstractItemModel [only showing the part for top items because that already fails]:

```
path = [self.rows[row]]
self.foobar.append(path) # Hack to make path stay alive
return self.createIndex(row, column, path)
```

and I later use them in data like this:

```
entries = index.internalPointer()
print("entries = {0}".format(entries))
entry = entries[0]
print("entry = {0}".format(entry))
```

This works fine as long as I have the self.foobar hack. If I remove that then entries is printed as '[[...], b'\n']' and python segfaults before printing entry. My guess is the QModelIndex does not keep the internal pointer alive so the GC frees it and later use gets corrupted data.

Obviously the self.foobar hack is not a proper solution. So how do I keep the path alive for however long the QModelIndex is around? I don't want to keep it around forever because only a small part of the matrix is visible at any one time (at most one row per window) and not having one item per row * column was the whole point of using an QAbstractModel.

Comment: The way to keep the `path` alive is to keep a reference to it, which is what you are doing by storing it in a list. If you don't want the data to stay alive "forever", try using a [WeakSet](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakSet) instead of a list.

Comment: WeakSet makes no sense. The path has no referers anymore so it gets deleted. It would just disapear from the set. I tried WeakKeyDictionary using the generated index as key and the path as value. But the View uses only the c++ part of the QModelIndex internally. PyQt forgets the generated QModelIndex and creates a new one when the View calls Model.data(). So the path drops from the WeakKeyDictionary too.
What I did now is store the user id as integer in the QModelIndex for roles and -1 for user. The stored user id + the index.row() then gives me all the info I need, luckily.

Comment: It does make sense: it just doesn't work ;-)